Accents on abbreviations of words
Do abbreviation of names that have an accent on the first letter, like
Évariste Galois
Étienne Ghys

keep the accent after in the abbreviation? Like É. Galois and É. Ghys, or is the accent dropped?

Fyi, in France, first names usually go second. Like the movie: Lacombe, Lucien.

@Lambie First names usually go first. They might go after the last name and a mandatory comma but only in very specific contexts where a list of people is sorted by last names: student lists at school, bibliography (like in English). Lacombe, Lucien title, intentionally reversed, is unique. See: Lucien Leuwen, Eugénie Grandet, Michel Strogoff, Thérèse Raquin, Thérèse Desqueyroux, César Birotteau, Manon Lescaut, Maria Chapdelaine, Mathias Sandorf, César Cascabel, Ange Pitou, Julie Lescaut, Hercule Poirot,  Adèle Blanc Sec, Michel Vaillant, Lola Montès, Violette Nozière, Camille Claudel, ...

@jlliagre In English, a bibliography is: Smith, John. In France: SMITH, John. [uppercase last name] All the mail I received from French companies or the sécu or other official letters were: SMITH, John. The only mail I received with John Smith were personal letters or formal invitations.'Here's a liste de participants from a German-French association: Nom, prénom
n°, rue,
code postal, ville liste-des-participants-20720%20(2).pdf And I was told that the upper case last name came from early IT data entry issues. And it  just stayed that wy.

Yes, Lacombe, Lucien was reversed to show that the kid was not the brightest on the block but that he was following protocol by saying his own name as it heard it in a line-up or other official call-up.

@Lambie Please don't derail this discussion. There was no mention of uppercase about which you are still incorrect anyway. You wrote in France, first names usually go second. The OED states usually means under normal conditions; generally.  Your statement is incorrect because in France, under normal conditions the first name goes before the last name. There are a few cases where it goes after, some of which you confirm to exist in English. This is unconsequential and doesn't apply to the question anyway. Both Évariste Galois and É. Galois are correctly written by the OP.

Could you kindly tell us where you plan to use this abbreviated first name? Thanks.

Outside acronyms, the rule tells to keep accents on uppercase letters.
However, that rule has been and is still very often broken, either for technical reasons (typewriters were lacking them, the current standard France French keyboard layout is not that better, as it doesn't show these letters) or just because it is not known enough.
See the BDL and this question.

Thanks for pointing the thread. Very interesting. I did go to a French School in Rio de Janeiro (Sacre Coeur de Marie) whre you would get slaped for accentuating a capital letter.

What a shame!  I hope you would have turned the other cheek though ;-)

for technical reasons... the current France French keyboard [cannot type accentuated capital letters] Ça, ça dépend de la configuration... Évidemment, les utilisateurs du clavier bépo sont avantagés. Über-célèbre, ce clavier ? À vrai dire, pas vraiment, mais ses utilisateurs peuvent frimer avec leurs majuscules accentuées !

@UJM For the English keyboard,  you  add the International Keyboard,

Le clavier BÉPO https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9po  — https://bepo.fr/wiki/Accueil résout tous les problèmes d'accent… en plus il est bon marché https://ldlc.com/informatique/peripherique-pc/clavier/c4606/…, on tape les lettres en 3 jours, les symboles usuels en une semaine sans regarder le clavier, les accents spécifiques à certaines langues ou translittérations demande un peu plus de temps. Compter une semaine laborieuse au début pour écrire en français ou anglais, plus une autre pour gérer les flèches et autres touches techniques… c'est pas une question de frime, mais d'efficacité et…

… utile pour le IAST https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Alphabet_of_Sanskrit_Transliteration

@Personne Tu touches une comm' dessus ? ;-)

Vu le tarif, ce n'est pas possible !! Ce clavier est pensé ergonomique, l'agencement des touches est optimisé pour la rapidité et l'intuition, et j'arrive à ne plus les regarder avec très peu de fautes de frappe, même dans les ¯ . · ˙— ú § …

@Personne Je plaisantais, bien sûr. J'ai cependant bien peur que ce clavier, malgré toutes ses qualités, soit un peu dans la même situation que l'espéranto vis à vis des langues occidentales ou le système métrique pour l'Américain moyen...

Créé pour l'Europe et ses nombreuses langues accentuées, et pour les translittérations indienne et chinoise (l'ensemble est un peu plus nombreux que les descendants du May Flower) il est très pratique pour les polyscribes (inconnus des dicos :-)

The site prairial.fr specializes in editorial/editing help:

Règle usuelle
La manière la plus usuelle d’abréger un prénom est de conserver la lettre initiale en majuscule, qu’on fait suivre d’un point.
C. (Coralie, Cédric)
M. (Michel, Martine)
O. (Olivier, Odile)
É. (Émile, Éva)
A. (Antoine, Audrey)

A little extra info:
And if there are two consonants for a single sound, the abbreviation uses both letters:

Ch. (Charles, Charlotte)
Gh. (Ghislain, Ghislaine)
Th. (Thérèse, Thomas)

OR followed by l or r:

Cl. (Clotilde, Clément)
Fr. (Françoise, Francis)
Chr. (Christophe, Christelle)

